# how to set values when Select2 is ready?

Tags: jquery-select2

Does `Select2` have any `onLoad` event so that I can set some default value? Now I resorted to some ugly trick after `Select2` is added to the `Dom` with the help of Ember's `didInsertElement`:

```
`setTimeout(function() {$select.select2('val', id).trigger('change'), 500});
```

I'm pretty sure there is a better solution out there :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may help you,

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("<option value='0'>Default</option>").insertBefore("option:nth-child(1)");
});
```